# Time Limit exceeded in python solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I was trying to solve the Leetcode question [Happy Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/) and I seem to be stuck in a weird Time Limit Exceeded Error.

My code:

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        def simu(n):
            sums = 0
            while n>0:
                s = n%10
                n = n//10
                sums=sums+(s**2)
            if sums != 1:
                simu(sums)
            return True
        while True:
            try:
                return simu(n)
            except RecursionError:
                return False
```

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: a case for which numbers are not happy is the recursion should end up to the same number. At least thats what I think so maybe your recursion is taking too long to hit the recursion error.

Comment: The question does not ask to return anything if the number is not happy but still I handled that error with the except RecursionError.

Comment: Hmm, meaning that a brute force method is too slow for Leetcode. You might need to think about how the mathematical solution can be simplified by looking at digits individually.

Comment: So you can tell that if any number returns to itself, that means its unhappy. And because patterns repeat, we can estimate that there will be a finite sequence before reaching some repetition of numbers. So I don't think you will face a memory issue by keeping a comparator. Have a solution if you want it but not sure if it passes leetcode

Comment: The `while True:` is not necessary

Comment: I don't uderstand why you use recursion for this.

Comment: now I understand problem - you can't loop endlestly. You have to recognize if it loops in cycle and return `False`. You have to recognize if it get the same result second time in loop. So you have to remeber numbers which you calculate and check if new value is on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Trying till you get a `RecursionError` is a very bad idea. Instead, one solution that I can think of is, keeping track of previously failed numbers and stop further attempts as soon as you get an already failed number. Because, you know for sure the same thing is going to happen again.

```
class Solution:
    def transform(self, n: int) -> int:
        s = 0
        while n > 0:
            d = n % 10
            s += d * d
            n = n // 10
        return s

    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        failed_hist = set()  # maybe you can preload this with some already known not-happy numbers
        while n not in failed_hist:  # continue as long as `n` has not failed before
            if n == 1:
                return True
            failed_hist.add(n)  # remember this failed !
            n = self.transform(n)  # transform `n` to it's next form
        return False  # loop broke, i.e. a failed `n` occured again
```

The idea is to demonstrate a solution without brute forcing. Maybe there can be better solutions, e.g. if those happy numbers have some special mathematical properties etc...